# Wrong result with mongoose .findOne() in .forEach loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to fetch, manipulate and save mongoose document but getting the wrong results. See code snippet below:

```
x = [{id:"abc", value:10, name:"andy"}, {id:"abc", value:20, name:"mark"}];

x.forEach(function(x){
  var amount = x.value;

  y.findOne({id:x.id}).populate("name").exec(function(err, y){
      y.value += amount;
      y.save();
  });
});
```

Each time I loop over the `forEach` and try to modify `y.value`, I get a wrong result.

```
Expected:
loop 1: y.value = 10;
loop 2: y.value = 30;

What I get:
loop 1: y.value = 10;
loop 2: y.value = 20;
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me out here.

Comment: `x.id` where is `id`  in json object `x = [{value:10, name:"andy"}, {value:20, name:"mark"}];` ?

Comment: Just updated the object. They both have the same id...this is hypothetical (of course ids will be unique)

Comment: id must be a valid Object id  like this `ObjectId("54759eb3c090d83494e2d804")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no

> id field

in Object x.
Just

```
x.value
```

and

```
x.name
```

are valid to retrieve.
So your query needs to be changed.

Also normally in MongoDB you just use the internal _id property to identify objects.
You have to be careful with normal foreach loops and asynchronous operations. You are better of using a library like

> async

or async/await